# Why does tag_invoke pattern need the Niebloid std::tag_invoke at all?

Tags: c++, tag-invoke, niebloid

This question assumes familiarity with the customization point management technique `tag_invoke`, introduced in [P1895R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1895r0.pdf).

A customization point object can be defined according to P1895R0 as:

```
inline constexpr struct foo_cpo {
    // simplified original by omitting noexcept forward and using auto arg
    auto operator()(auto const &x) -> decltype( std::tag_invoke(*this, x) ) {
        return std::tag_invoke(*this, x); // <--^-- here are the Niebloid
    }
} foo;
```

But given the crux of this technique is to work with objects directly, and delegate any and all ADL to one and only agreed-upon identifier `tag_invoke`, then it *seems* the same effects can be achieved by simply,

```
inline constexpr struct {
    auto operator()(auto const &x) -> decltype( tag_invoke(*this, x) ) {
        return tag_invoke(*this, x); // no Niebloid. directly ADL call tag_invoke
    }
} foo;
```

For instance, the type erasure example from P1895R0, which is https://godbolt.org/z/3TvO4f, can be reimplemented without using the Niebloid at all: https://godbolt.org/z/dzqE7b. The code is the same as the original verbatim, modulo the definition of the Niebloid `std::tag_invoke` and using the above ADL form for all customization points objects.

What is the requirement that the presence of Niebloid really satisfies for `tag_invoke`?

Comment: There is no niebloid anywhere here. `std::tag_invoke` is _not_ a niebloid.

Comment: Barry, the distinction between what cppreference.com means by "niebloid" and what the standard calls a "customization point object" is interesting only Committee wonks, I think. I've given up trying to draw a distinction, and I think eventually the Committee will cave and call these things objects as they really are. It's all the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think it's strictly necessary for `tag_invoke` itself to be a function object. But defining it as an object gives us a handy place to put a poison-pill overload should we decide that's necessary. And it's generally nice to have functions as first-class citizens that can be passed to higher-order functions. That's it, really.

Comment: hey thanks!  you mean to catch things like this: https://godbolt.org/z/nr7h3j ?

Comment: what is the use case to pass std::tag_invoke itself around? wouldn't we just pass CPOs? or rather, even if we passed std::tag_invoke, wouldn't we need to also pass CPOs anyway?

Comment: Nick, yes, a poison pill overload helps in cases of accidental hijacking like that. As for _why_ someone would pass `tag_invoke` to a higher-order function, I don't know, but my imagination is pretty limited.